# Passing Credential on Invoke-RestMethod for AzureDevOps API to Retrieve Users

Tags: api, azure, powershell, automation, azure-devops

I am trying to create a powershell script that will retrieve a number of users from AzureDevOps organization using REST API. I have encrypted my password and placed it in credentials, however I am getting an error like this:

```
Invoke-RestMethod : Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 
'Credential'. 
 userName
At D:\Others\Retrieve Users.ps1:11 char:80
+ ... stakeholderUrl -Method Get -Credential $webclient.Credentials).identi 
...
+                                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Invoke-RestMethod], 
    ParameterBindingArgumentTransformationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : 
ParameterArgumentTransformationError,Microsoft.PowerShell.
Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

Here is my Powershell Script Code:

```
$stakeholderUrl = 
"https://vsaex.dev.azure.com/[organizationName]/_apis/userentitlements?api- 
version=5.0-preview.2"

$password = Get-Content D:\GetUsers\password.txt | ConvertTo-SecureString - 
Key (Get-Content D:\GetUsers\aes.key)
$credential = New-Object 
System.Net.NetworkCredential("sample@abc.com",$password)


$stakeholder = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $stakeholderUrl -Method Get - 
Credential $credential).identities

$StakeholderUsers = @()

foreach($user in $stakeholder){

$customObject = new-object PSObject -property @{
      "Display Name" = $user.displayName
      "Email" = $user.mailAddress
      "License" = $user.licenseDisplayName
    } 

$StakeholderUsers += $customObject      
}

$StakeholderUsers | Select `
            displayName,
            mailAddress, 
            licenseDisplayName
```

I would appreciate if you could help me on this.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you use the Microsoft credential or alternate credential?

Answer (score 2):

Store the credentials in this way:

```
domain\username:password

$Credentials= Get-Content D:\GetUsers\Credentials.txt
```

Create the Base64-encoded Basic authorization header:

```
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}" -f $Credentials)))
```

Invoke the rest:

```
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Get -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
```

Comment: Hello Shayki, I have not tested it out but I will give you an update on this one. Thank you for this.

Comment: I am not receiving error anymore but I maintained the password encryption. I followed: $base64AuthInfo and $result. When I try to run the code, it doesn't show any errors however, there is no output. It just says complete. Here's the code:

Comment: `code`

$uri = "https://vsaex.dev.azure.com/[OrgName]/_apis/userentitlements?api-version=5.0-preview.2"

$password = Get-Content D:\GetUsers\password.txt | ConvertTo-SecureString -Key (Get-Content D:\GetUsers\aes.key)
$Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("sample@abc.com",$password)
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}" -f $Credentials)))

$result = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Get -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}).identities `code`

Comment: `code`

$resultUsers = @()

foreach($user in $result){

    $customObject = new-object PSObject -Property @{
          "Display Name" = $user.displayName
          "Email" = $user.mailAddress
          "License" = $user.licenseDisplayName
        } 

    $resultUsers += $customObject      
}

$resultUsers | Select `
                displayName,
                mailAddress, 
                licenseDisplayName


`code`

Comment: Don't use the `secure string` and `System.Net.NetworkCredential`

Comment: following your advise, I am now getting this error:

Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
At D:\Others\Version 3 Retrieve Users.ps1:6 char:12
+ $result = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Get -ContentType "appl ...
+            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) 
    [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands. 
   InvokeRestMethodCommand

Comment: I have placed my password in the Credentials.txt with the exact format as you stated from the above. and then added $base64AuthInfo and then sa $result.